# What is the reference of the statement that Umm Salamah nursed al-Hassan al-Basri?

Tags: history, authenticity, reference-request

[Al-Hassan al-Basri](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hasan_al-Basri&oldid=1188113719) is a known Tabi'i who was born two years before the death of 'Umar ibn al-Khattab in Medina and grow up in the house of Umm Salamah () the wive of the prophet ().
A couple of years ago while looking for subjects for a Khotbah I found on [al-Minbar](http://www.alminbar.net/alkhutab/khutbaa.asp?mediaURL=3098) a khotba telling his biography and this starts with the statement that al-Hassan's Mother Khayra was a servant in the house of Umm Salamah () and when she left the house for some purposes Umm Salamah nursed him as baby to calm him and therefore she breast fed him as [Arabic Wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A&oldid=65345540) confirms.

My question is the (Muslim) source/reference of the story and if possible its authenticity?